# What is the most effective way to keep titles above a ListView aligned with the data in the ListView?

Tags: flutter

I'm kinda a loser when it comes to formatting and I've come to the conclusion I need a little guidance/advice. I have a ListView populated with cards that display data in them. Above this ListView I have the titles for the data in the ListView. Along with a search bar, but that shouldn't affect much. I'm having issues making the titles stay aligned with the data in the cards below, especially when switching between different devices since the screen size changes. What is the best way to do this? Any help and/or advice is highly appreciated!

This is an image of how it looks currently

[image: This is how it looks]

This is the current code. I'm using a combination of flex and expanded for most of my formatting for moving the data & titles around.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(95.0),
          child: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // hides leading widget
            flexibleSpace: DataAppBar(onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                newValue = newValue;
              });
            }),
          ),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
            stream: DataDBProvider.dataDB.getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              List data = snapshot.data;
              return Column(children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .45,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05,
                          child: TextField(
                          controller: editingController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Search",
                              hintText: "Search",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
                        ),)),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              "Date",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.green, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                            ),
                          )),
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

                          child: Text(
                            "Item",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.green, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,

                          child: Text(
                            "Amount",
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.green, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onLongPress: () =>
                              _openUpdateDrawer(data[index]),
                          child: Card(
                            color: (index % 2 == 0) ? greycolor : Colors.white,
                            child: Container(
                                height: 60,
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Flexible(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 5, top: 13),
                                            child: AutoSizeText(
                                                data[index].date,
                                                maxFontSize: 12,
                                                minFontSize: 7,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Flexible(
                                      flex: 4,
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 13, left: 10),
                                            child: Text(
                                              data[index].title,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Flexible(
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                                child: AutoSizeText(
                                                  '${data[index].description}',
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontStyle:
                                                          FontStyle.italic),
                                                ),
                                              ))
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                            child: AutoSizeText(
                                                '\$${data[index].amount}',
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ),
                        ));
                  },
                ))
              ]);
            }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are adding extra padding in your elements in the listview that you need to add to the titles:

```
    padding:
      EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),  // add margin to accomplish offsetting the labels the same as the items
```

So now in the titles you can add either padding or margin for 8 to the left. This only applies to the first two though. So for the final one you can do this:

```
    Flexible(
       flex: 2,
         child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.end, // changed from center to end
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:8), // add the right margin

            child: Text(
               "Amount",
               maxLines: 1,
               style: TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.green, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
```

also just a friendly piece of advice is that you are making this a whole lot more complicated on your self than needed. The above answers your question but I would consider trying to clean up your code so future questions/problems are easier to identify.